# CSS: hide one scrollbar in bootstrap modalWindow

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In my app i use bootstrap. And **my page must always be with scrollbar**. And now i have one trouble: if my modal is very big (by height) - i get two side scroll bars...

is it real to scroll modal only with one scroll bar?

part of html-css:

```
html{
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

what i mean is here:

[image: modal scrollbar]

and here is plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/QHpjmpQHW1vZWd69Tm7A?p=preview

is it real to use only one scroll? And how?

Comment: weird.. its working on my local machine well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i didnt realize you had updated your question to say that you MUST have it set like that. In that case you need to add jQuery. I would try something like this:

```
$("#myModal").on("show.modal.bs", function(){
   $('html').css("overflow-y", "hidden");
});
$("#myModal").on("hidden.modal.bs", function(){
   $('html').css("overflow-y", "scroll");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue. I fixed it with jQuery. When you open your modal, add an event to add the `modal-open` class to your `html` element.

```
$('html').addClass('modal-open');
```

When you close your modal, add an event to remove the `modal-open` class from your `html` element.

```
$('html').removeClass('modal-open');
```

Comment: maybe fiddle? or plunker?

Comment: will see... on first look is ok

Comment: Actually you need to remove the class when you close the modal to see the scrollbar again, I updated my answer. Here is the new plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/bvFnrNcGQ9uiJrzD9tIq?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

I tried it on my local machine, and it works well, so then I tried it on **[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9ve86xmd/)**, and it also works well. I believe the problem lies on  that Plunker website youre using..

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.3" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    Launch demo modal
  </button>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sagittis, metus sed ornare sodales, sapien eros efficitur est, vitae interdum diam lacus a nulla. Aliquam nec mollis mauris, in facilisis est. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque a dictum
      dolor. Nunc nec nisl mauris. Quisque a consequat diam, eu bibendum magna. Aenean felis mi, rutrum in enim eget, venenatis accumsan augue. Pellentesque vel volutpat lacus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Proin tinciduntcommodo orci ut mollis. Ut pellentesque
      tristique sapien, at vehicula mauris congue in. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sagittis, metus sed ornare sodales, sapien eros efficitur est, vitae interdum diam lacus a nulla. Aliquam nec mollis mauris, in facilisis est. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque a dictum
      dolor. Nunc nec nisl mauris. Quisque a consequat diam, eu bibendum magna. Aenean felis mi, rutrum in enim eget, venenatis accumsan augue. Pellentesque vel volutpat lacus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Proin tinciduntcommodo orci ut mollis. Ut pellentesque
      tristique sapien, at vehicula mauris congue in. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sagittis, metus sed ornare sodales, sapien eros efficitur est, vitae interdum diam lacus a nulla. Aliquam nec mollis mauris, in facilisis est. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque a dictum
      dolor. Nunc nec nisl mauris. Quisque a consequat diam, eu bibendum magna. Aenean felis mi, rutrum in enim eget, venenatis accumsan augue. Pellentesque vel volutpat lacus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Proin tinciduntcommodo orci ut mollis. Ut pellentesque
      tristique sapien, at vehicula mauris congue in. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sagittis, metus sed ornare sodales, sapien eros efficitur est, vitae interdum diam lacus a nulla. Aliquam nec mollis mauris, in facilisis est. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque a dictum
      dolor. Nunc nec nisl mauris. Quisque a consequat diam, eu bibendum magna. Aenean felis mi, rutrum in enim eget, venenatis accumsan augue. Pellentesque vel volutpat lacus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Proin tinciduntcommodo orci ut mollis. Ut pellentesque
      tristique sapien, at vehicula mauris congue in. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sagittis, metus sed ornare sodales, sapien eros efficitur est, vitae interdum diam lacus a nulla. Aliquam nec mollis mauris, in facilisis est. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque a dictum
      dolor. Nunc nec nisl mauris. Quisque a consequat diam, eu bibendum magna. Aenean felis mi, rutrum in enim eget, venenatis accumsan augue. Pellentesque vel volutpat lacus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Proin tinciduntcommodo orci ut mollis. Ut pellentesque
      tristique sapien, at vehicula mauris congue in. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sagittis, metus sed ornare sodales, sapien eros efficitur est, vitae interdum diam lacus a nulla. Aliquam nec mollis mauris, in facilisis est. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque a dictum
      dolor. Nunc nec nisl mauris. Quisque a consequat diam, eu bibendum magna. Aenean felis mi, rutrum in enim eget, venenatis accumsan augue. Pellentesque vel volutpat lacus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Proin tinciduntcommodo orci ut mollis. Ut pellentesque
      tristique sapien, at vehicula mauris congue in. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sagittis, metus sed ornare sodales, sapien eros efficitur est, vitae interdum diam lacus a nulla. Aliquam nec mollis mauris, in facilisis est. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque a dictum
      dolor. Nunc nec nisl mauris. Quisque a consequat diam, eu bibendum magna. Aenean felis mi, rutrum in enim eget, venenatis accumsan augue. Pellentesque vel volutpat lacus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Proin tinciduntcommodo orci ut mollis. Ut pellentesque
      tristique sapien, at vehicula mauris congue in. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sagittis, metus sed ornare sodales, sapien eros efficitur est, vitae interdum diam lacus a nulla. Aliquam nec mollis mauris, in facilisis est. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque a dictum
      dolor. Nunc nec nisl mauris. Quisque a consequat diam, eu bibendum magna. Aenean felis mi, rutrum in enim eget, venenatis accumsan augue. Pellentesque vel volutpat lacus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Proin tinciduntcommodo orci ut mollis. Ut pellentesque
      tristique sapien, at vehicula mauris congue in. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sagittis, metus sed ornare sodales, sapien eros efficitur est, vitae interdum diam lacus a nulla. Aliquam nec mollis mauris, in facilisis est. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque a dictum
      dolor. Nunc nec nisl mauris. Quisque a consequat diam, eu bibendum magna. Aenean felis mi, rutrum in enim eget, venenatis accumsan augue. Pellentesque vel volutpat lacus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Proin tinciduntcommodo orci ut mollis. Ut pellentesque
      tristique sapien, at vehicula mauris congue in. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sagittis, metus sed ornare sodales, sapien eros efficitur est, vitae interdum diam lacus a nulla. Aliquam nec mollis mauris, in facilisis est. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque a dictum
      dolor. Nunc nec nisl mauris. Quisque a consequat diam, eu bibendum magna. Aenean felis mi, rutrum in enim eget, venenatis accumsan augue. Pellentesque vel volutpat lacus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Proin tinciduntcommodo orci ut mollis. Ut pellentesque
      tristique sapien, at vehicula mauris congue in. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sagittis, metus sed ornare sodales, sapien eros efficitur est, vitae interdum diam lacus a nulla. Aliquam nec mollis mauris, in facilisis est. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque a dictum
      dolor. Nunc nec nisl mauris. Quisque a consequat diam, eu bibendum magna. Aenean felis mi, rutrum in enim eget, venenatis accumsan augue. Pellentesque vel volutpat lacus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Proin tinciduntcommodo orci ut mollis. Ut pellentesque
      tristique sapien, at vehicula mauris congue in. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sagittis, metus sed ornare sodales, sapien eros efficitur est, vitae interdum diam lacus a nulla. Aliquam nec mollis mauris, in facilisis est. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque a dictum
      dolor. Nunc nec nisl mauris. Quisque a consequat diam, eu bibendum magna. Aenean felis mi, rutrum in enim eget, venenatis accumsan augue. Pellentesque vel volutpat lacus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Proin tinciduntcommodo orci ut mollis. Ut pellentesque
      tristique sapien, at vehicula mauris congue in. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sagittis, metus sed ornare sodales, sapien eros efficitur est, vitae interdum diam lacus a nulla. Aliquam nec mollis mauris, in facilisis est. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque a dictum
      dolor. Nunc nec nisl mauris. Quisque a consequat diam, eu bibendum magna. Aenean felis mi, rutrum in enim eget, venenatis accumsan augue. Pellentesque vel volutpat lacus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Proin tinciduntcommodo orci ut mollis. Ut pellentesque
      tristique sapien, at vehicula mauris congue in. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sagittis, metus sed ornare sodales, sapien eros efficitur est, vitae interdum diam lacus a nulla. Aliquam nec mollis mauris, in facilisis est. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque a dictum
      dolor. Nunc nec nisl mauris. Quisque a consequat diam, eu bibendum magna. Aenean felis mi, rutrum in enim eget, venenatis accumsan augue. Pellentesque vel volutpat lacus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Proin tinciduntcommodo orci ut mollis. Ut pellentesque
      tristique sapien, at vehicula mauris congue in. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sagittis, metus sed ornare sodales, sapien eros efficitur est, vitae interdum diam lacus a nulla. Aliquam nec mollis mauris, in facilisis est. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque a dictum
      dolor. Nunc nec nisl mauris. Quisque a consequat diam, eu bibendum magna. Aenean felis mi, rutrum in enim eget, venenatis accumsan augue. Pellentesque vel volutpat lacus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Proin tinciduntcommodo orci ut mollis. Ut pellentesque
      tristique sapien, at vehicula mauris congue in. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sagittis, metus sed ornare sodales, sapien eros efficitur est, vitae interdum diam lacus a nulla. Aliquam nec mollis mauris, in facilisis est. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque a dictum
      dolor. Nunc nec nisl mauris. Quisque a consequat diam, eu bibendum magna. Aenean felis mi, rutrum in enim eget, venenatis accumsan augue. Pellentesque vel volutpat lacus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Proin tinciduntcommodo orci ut mollis. Ut pellentesque
      tristique sapien, at vehicula mauris congue in. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sagittis, metus sed ornare sodales, sapien eros efficitur est, vitae interdum diam lacus a nulla. Aliquam nec mollis mauris, in facilisis est. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque a dictum
      dolor. Nunc nec nisl mauris. Quisque a consequat diam, eu bibendum magna. Aenean felis mi, rutrum in enim eget, venenatis accumsan augue. Pellentesque vel volutpat lacus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Proin tinciduntcommodo orci ut mollis. Ut pellentesque
      tristique sapien, at vehicula mauris congue in. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sagittis, metus sed ornare sodales, sapien eros efficitur est, vitae interdum diam lacus a nulla. Aliquam nec mollis mauris, in facilisis est. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque a dictum
      dolor. Nunc nec nisl mauris. Quisque a consequat diam, eu bibendum magna. Aenean felis mi, rutrum in enim eget, venenatis accumsan augue. Pellentesque vel volutpat lacus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Proin tinciduntcommodo orci ut mollis. Ut pellentesque
      tristique sapien, at vehicula mauris congue in. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.</p>
  </div>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sagittis, metus sed ornare sodales, sapien eros efficitur est, vitae interdum diam lacus a nulla. Aliquam nec mollis mauris, in facilisis est. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque
            a dictum dolor. Nunc nec nisl mauris. Quisque a consequat diam, eu bibendum magna. Aenean felis mi, rutrum in enim eget, venenatis accumsan augue. Pellentesque vel volutpat lacus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Proin tinciduntcommodo orci ut mollis.
            Ut pellentesque tristique sapien, at vehicula mauris congue in. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sagittis, metus sed ornare sodales, sapien eros efficitur est, vitae interdum diam lacus a nulla. Aliquam nec mollis mauris, in facilisis est. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque
            a dictum dolor. Nunc nec nisl mauris. Quisque a consequat diam, eu bibendum magna. Aenean felis mi, rutrum in enim eget, venenatis accumsan augue. Pellentesque vel volutpat lacus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Proin tinciduntcommodo orci ut mollis.
            Ut pellentesque tristique sapien, at vehicula mauris congue in. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sagittis, metus sed ornare sodales, sapien eros efficitur est, vitae interdum diam lacus a nulla. Aliquam nec mollis mauris, in facilisis est. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque
            a dictum dolor. Nunc nec nisl mauris. Quisque a consequat diam, eu bibendum magna. Aenean felis mi, rutrum in enim eget, venenatis accumsan augue. Pellentesque vel volutpat lacus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Proin tinciduntcommodo orci ut mollis.
            Ut pellentesque tristique sapien, at vehicula mauris congue in. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sagittis, metus sed ornare sodales, sapien eros efficitur est, vitae interdum diam lacus a nulla. Aliquam nec mollis mauris, in facilisis est. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque
            a dictum dolor. Nunc nec nisl mauris. Quisque a consequat diam, eu bibendum magna. Aenean felis mi, rutrum in enim eget, venenatis accumsan augue. Pellentesque vel volutpat lacus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Proin tinciduntcommodo orci ut mollis.
            Ut pellentesque tristique sapien, at vehicula mauris congue in. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sagittis, metus sed ornare sodales, sapien eros efficitur est, vitae interdum diam lacus a nulla. Aliquam nec mollis mauris, in facilisis est. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque
            a dictum dolor. Nunc nec nisl mauris. Quisque a consequat diam, eu bibendum magna. Aenean felis mi, rutrum in enim eget, venenatis accumsan augue. Pellentesque vel volutpat lacus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Proin tinciduntcommodo orci ut mollis.
            Ut pellentesque tristique sapien, at vehicula mauris congue in. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sagittis, metus sed ornare sodales, sapien eros efficitur est, vitae interdum diam lacus a nulla. Aliquam nec mollis mauris, in facilisis est. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque
            a dictum dolor. Nunc nec nisl mauris. Quisque a consequat diam, eu bibendum magna. Aenean felis mi, rutrum in enim eget, venenatis accumsan augue. Pellentesque vel volutpat lacus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Proin tinciduntcommodo orci ut mollis.
            Ut pellentesque tristique sapien, at vehicula mauris congue in. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sagittis, metus sed ornare sodales, sapien eros efficitur est, vitae interdum diam lacus a nulla. Aliquam nec mollis mauris, in facilisis est. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque
            a dictum dolor. Nunc nec nisl mauris. Quisque a consequat diam, eu bibendum magna. Aenean felis mi, rutrum in enim eget, venenatis accumsan augue. Pellentesque vel volutpat lacus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Proin tinciduntcommodo orci ut mollis.
            Ut pellentesque tristique sapien, at vehicula mauris congue in. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sagittis, metus sed ornare sodales, sapien eros efficitur est, vitae interdum diam lacus a nulla. Aliquam nec mollis mauris, in facilisis est. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque
            a dictum dolor. Nunc nec nisl mauris. Quisque a consequat diam, eu bibendum magna. Aenean felis mi, rutrum in enim eget, venenatis accumsan augue. Pellentesque vel volutpat lacus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Proin tinciduntcommodo orci ut mollis.
            Ut pellentesque tristique sapien, at vehicula mauris congue in. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sagittis, metus sed ornare sodales, sapien eros efficitur est, vitae interdum diam lacus a nulla. Aliquam nec mollis mauris, in facilisis est. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque
            a dictum dolor. Nunc nec nisl mauris. Quisque a consequat diam, eu bibendum magna. Aenean felis mi, rutrum in enim eget, venenatis accumsan augue. Pellentesque vel volutpat lacus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Proin tinciduntcommodo orci ut mollis.
            Ut pellentesque tristique sapien, at vehicula mauris congue in. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<script>
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: still works for me in all resolutions.. can you provide more information of your environment? is this problem happening on your local machine as well? what browser?

Comment: all browsers, plukner, localProject, another computer: same

Comment: if you click "Run code snippet" on the code i provided above, do you see the same problem?

Comment: i would try removing any other styling or JS you have linked to your page to see if the problem still occurs. Something must be conflicting with the CSS.

Comment: it's ok... hm strange

Comment: I think you have a `style.css` linked to your page with `html{overflow-y:scroll;}` on line 3. You need to remove that.

Comment: pfff.... no no no!!!! scroll must be everywhere: see you example: when you will have empty html, but huge text...modal

Comment: @brabertaser1992 Did you try the jQuery code I provided in my answer ?